# .Net 4.0 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ClassName]' to type 'ClassName'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, c#-4.0

```
public class SkillView {
public string Name { get; set; } 
public IList<SkillValueView> Selected { get; set; }}

public class SkillValueView {
    public string APlan { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }}

private IList<SkillValueView> MapToSkillValueList(IGrouping<string, GetSession_Result> query)
    {
        var actionItem = query.FirstOrDefault();
        List<SkillValueView> LSVV = new List<SkillValueView>();
        SkillValueView SVV = new SkillValueView();

        for (int i = 0; i < actionItem.NoOf; i++)
            {
                SVV.APlan = actionItem.ExAPlan;
                SVV.DueDate = actionItem.ExDueDate;
                LSVV.Add(new SkillValueView() { APlan = SVV.APlan, DueDate = SVV.DueDate });
            }
        }
        return LSVV;
    }

private SkillView MapToSkill(IGrouping<int, GetSession_Result> query){
    var skill = query.FirstOrDefault();
    return new SkillView()
        {
            Name = skill.SkillName,
            Selected = query.GroupBy(s => s.ExAPlan).Select(MapToSkillValueList).ToList()
        }; 
}
```

I am unable to map this >**Selected = query.GroupBy(s => s.ExAPlan).Select(MapToSkillValueList).ToList()** and getting an error *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IsaiX.Coach.Models.SkillValueView]' to type 'IsaiX.Coach.Models.SkillValueView'.*

Comment: I believe you are looking for `SelectMany` instead of `Select`. `query.GroupBy(s => s.ExAPlan).SelectMany(MapToSkillValueList).ToList()`. "SelectMany flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence"

Comment: Thanks @Igor it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should be using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) instead of `Select`.

```
query.GroupBy(s => s.ExAPlan).SelectMany(MapToSkillValueList).ToList().
```

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence